# Two images, one resizing, one not resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, image-resizing

I have an 800px div containing side-by-side images, the first being a photo and the other a map.  Since the 300px map has detail that renders it useless when downsized, I don't want it to resize at all on smaller screens.  The photo, however, should resize indefinitely without forcing the map to wrap around and appear below it.

I'm guessing that with two separate containers this would be easier, but is it possible with just one container?  Currently the code is:

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.photo {
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.map {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

<div class="container">
  <img class="photo" src="photo.jpg">
  <img class="map" src="map.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you still want them to be side by side if the screen is resized?

Comment: Yes, I want them side by side.  Obviously when the screen size is down to about 400px, there won't be much left of the photo, but I will simply make it disappear with a media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/theskumar/full/tHwjo

The codepen can be found here: http://codepen.io/theskumar/pen/tHwjo

*Use browser resizing to see the effect.*

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"> </div>
  <div class="map"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x400"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container{
  position: relative;

  /* for demo */
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.photo {
  margin-right: 300px;

  /* for demo */
  height: 400px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;

  /* for demo */
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 400px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, Saurabh, but I notice that the photo (on the left) resized the width, but it doesn't proportionally scale down in height.  I tried resetting the code to auto, but without success.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I had overlooked that you created two separate divs, one for the image and one for the map. I simply changed the photos height to auto, and your code works exactly as I needed.  Thanks a million.

Comment: You don't even need to put `height: auto` explicitly. If you remove the `height: 400px` it will work fine as `auto` is default behaviour. Also you should mark the answer as `accepted/correct` for others coming here. cheers!

Comment: This was definitely the answer I was looking for.  The problem is that there is nowhere, not a button nor a link, that I can find to mark this as answered.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yOUR CODE  might be

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:auto;
    }
    .photo {
      float: left;
width:calc(100%-300px);
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .map {
      float: right;
      width: 300px;
min-width:300px;
      height: 250px;
    }

<div class="container">
  <img class="photo" src="photo.jpg">
  <img class="map" src="map.png">
</div>
```

check and let me know

Comment: what are views of using `calc` with cross browser compatibility in mind?